# Jenkins pipeline poll scm to ignore certain users?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a Jenkinsfile to customize my build and figured out that the following sets polling:

```
triggers {
  pollSCM '*/10 * * * *'
}
```

However, I need to add the option to ignore commits by certain users. I'm not seeing that option in the UI config. I'm configured to use Jenkins Pipeline. Anyone know how to do this in the Jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 1):

If you dig into the `currentBuild.changeSets` variable, you can call `getItems`. This will return a collection of [`Entry`s](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/scm/ChangeLogSet.Entry.html) at which point you can look at calling `getAuthor()` on the `Entry` and `getDisplayName()` on the `User` object returned by `getAuthor()`. You can just add conditional logic around that `getDisplayName()` return value at that point.

I'm not 100% sure on how this would translate to the declarative pipeline syntax, and may require some method whitelisting.